# Integral curves which lead to concentric circles

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, vector-fields, mathematics

I want to find out the integral curves of this vector field: $$\vec{V}=x\,\partial/\partial y-y\,\partial/\partial x.$$
Given the equation for integral curves:
$$dx^i/d\lambda=V^i(x^j)$$
I get:
$$dx^1/d\lambda=dx/d\lambda=-y$$
$$dx^2/d\lambda=dy/d\lambda=x.$$
Differentiating both of these equations with respect to $\lambda$ I get two 2nd order differential equations:
$$d^2x/d\lambda^2=-x$$
$$d^2y/d\lambda^2=-y.$$
The solutions to these equations are obviously sinusoids.
But this is where I am confused: For 2nd Order ODEs we need two initial conditions, so we have four initial conditions, but as far as I know the Integral curve equation is a set of two first order ODEs, so they should require in total only 2 initial conditions.

Comment: Using $x'  =-y$ and $y' = x$, your two initial conditions become four.

Comment: Ah ok I got it. thanks

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic maybe it would. But I was doing this for a seminar in geometrical methods in mathematical physics.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions to the second order ODEs are:
$$x(\lambda)=A\,cos(\lambda)+B\,sin(\lambda)$$
$$y(\lambda)=C\,cos(\lambda)+D\, sin(\lambda)$$
With the intial conditions $$x(0)=x_0 \,\, \, y(0)=y_0$$
One gets that $A=x_0$ and $B=y_0$.
Using the first order ODEs one can easily find that $B=-y_0$ and $D=x_0$